# Child of Constraint and object hierarchy

Tags: rigging

I have a problem with constraints: I use [`Child Of`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/child_of.html) constraints to animate the parent of objects (e.g. robot passes part to another robot). All objects should be grouped under a master parent (empty).

If an object has a *Child Of* contraint and at the same time is the child of the master parent, then it gets twice the values ​​and thus an offset.

The blue cube is bound to the master by *Child Of* and in the second screenshot in the hierarchy, an offset is created, when the master is moved.

[image]

[image]

The animation is baked and exported to a real-time engine (Unity), so it's important to me that the objects are neatly arranged in the hierarchy.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

BSE -

There are 3 cubes, Red, Fawn & Blue.

Blue is a child of Fawn.

A master handle is parenting all 3.  When the master moves, it takes Red & Fawn ok, but Blue would move twice the distance.  That's because the child-of constraint is still parenting Blue to Fawn.

The solution, (if the Child-of constraint must remain) is to limit the master parent to just Red & Fawn.
Blue will then follow Fawn normally, not the master and all 3 will move aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround to use child of contraints and keep clean hierarchy:
You can use an armature with a **bone constraint** child of and parent your mesh to this bone.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).